# Why when I press two keys simultaneously and stop pressing one, the other stops working?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, keydown, keyup

I am working with keyboard events in Javascript. My goal is to be able to move images on a canvas with the keyboard arrows, but there is a problem: when I press two keys simultaneously and then release one of them, the key I left pressed does not work, it crashes and therefore the image It does not move. I'm already using the keyup and keydown events and I managed to find a way to detect when two keys are pressed at the same time, however I can't solve this problem. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

[this is what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQQH0.png)

```
function keyPressed(event) {
  keysPressed[event.key] = true;
  
  switch(event.key) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      playerPetSelected.speedX = -5;
      break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
      playerPetSelected.speedX = 5;
      break;
    case 'ArrowDown':
      playerPetSelected.speedY = 5;
      break;
    case 'ArrowUp':
      playerPetSelected.speedY = -5;
      break;
  }
  
  if (keysPressed['ArrowLeft'] && event.key == 'ArrowDown') {
    playerPetSelected.speedX = -3.5;
    playerPetSelected.speedY = 3.5;
  }
  if (keysPressed['ArrowDown'] && event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
    playerPetSelected.speedY = 3.5;
    playerPetSelected.speedX = -3.5;
  }
  if (keysPressed['ArrowLeft'] && event.key == 'ArrowUp') {
    playerPetSelected.speedX = -3.5;
    playerPetSelected.speedY = -3.5;
  }
  if (keysPressed['ArrowUp'] && event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
    playerPetSelected.speedY = -3.5;
    playerPetSelected.speedX = -3.5;
  }
  if (keysPressed['ArrowUp'] && event.key == 'ArrowRight') {
    playerPetSelected.speedY = -3.5;
    playerPetSelected.speedX = 3.5;
  }
  if (keysPressed['ArrowRight'] && event.key == 'ArrowUp') {
    playerPetSelected.speedX = 3.5;
    playerPetSelected.speedY = -3.5;
  }
  if (keysPressed['ArrowDown'] && event.key == 'ArrowRight') {
    playerPetSelected.speedY = 3.5;
    playerPetSelected.speedX = 3.5;
  }
  if (keysPressed['ArrowRight'] && event.key == 'ArrowDown') {
    playerPetSelected.speedX = 3.5;
    playerPetSelected.speedY = 3.5;
  }
}
  
function stopMovement(event) {
  keysPressed[event.key] = false;
  playerPetSelected.speedX = 0;
  playerPetSelected.speedY = 0;
}
```

The parts where I modify the 'playerPetSelected' object are so that the images can be moved on the canvas.

I was hoping I wouldn't have this problem anymore because here I was able to find a way to detect when two keys are pressed at the same time, but it only helped me to manipulate the speed of movement on the canvas when two keys are pressed simultaneously.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: You should check if there is a key that is still pressed in the `keysPressed` object. Actually, you are setting x and y speeds at 0 as soon as a `keyup` event fires. - For any more detailed answer, you have to post your code in the body of your question. Look at [formatting on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I took it on me to edit your question... Because it's your first. Do not expect that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it... Using an object for the speed in x/y. Look how the conditions are easier to read. That handles all possible arrow combinations.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPressed)
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUnpressed)

let keysPressed = {}

function keyPressed(event) {
  keysPressed[event.key] = true
  getActiveKeys()
}

function keyUnpressed(event) {
  keysPressed[event.key] = false
  getActiveKeys()
}

function getActiveKeys() {
  const activeKeys = Object.keys(keysPressed).map((key) => keysPressed[key] ? key : null).filter((key) => key)

  const speed = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }
  
  if(keysPressed["ArrowUp"]){
    speed.y = 5
  }
  if(keysPressed["ArrowDown"]){
    speed.y = -5
  }
  if(keysPressed["ArrowLeft"]){
    speed.x = -5
  }
  if(keysPressed["ArrowRight"]){
    speed.x = 5
  }
  
  // Gas and break conditions
  if(keysPressed["ArrowUp"] && keysPressed["ArrowDown"]){
    speed.y = 0
  }
  if(keysPressed["ArrowLeft"] && keysPressed["ArrowRight"]){
    speed.x = 0
  }
  
  // Diagonal condition
  if(speed.x && speed.y){
    speed.x *= 0.7
    speed.y *= 0.7
  }
  
  document.querySelector("#activeKeys").innerText = JSON.stringify(activeKeys)
  document.querySelector("#xSpeed").innerText = speed.x
  document.querySelector("#ySpeed").innerText = speed.y
}
```

```html
<div>Keys pressed: <span id="activeKeys">[]</span></div>
<div>Speed X: <span id="xSpeed">0</span></div>
<div>Speed Y: <span id="ySpeed">0</span></div>
```

Run that snippet in full page mode, else the page will scroll. Or look at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/abjmOXg?editors=0010)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and sorry for posting this question like this, it's already clear to me how I should do it for the next one, as you said, it's my first question so I'm just learning. Greetings and thanks for everything